# MySQL get row (out of duplicates) with biggest difference between columns

Tags: mysql

I heve the following two tables in MySQL.

**Items**

| code | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 8 |

**Locations**

| code | min | max | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 | loc1 |
| 1 | 4 | 9 | loc2 |
| 2 | 6 | 10 | loc3 |

I want to get the location for each `code` in `Items`, where there is the biggest difference between `min` and `max`. For `code=1`, there are two locations assigned, `loc1` and `loc2`, but the correct one is `loc2` because `9-4` is bigger than `8-5`.

The **output** would be

| code | value | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | loc2 |
| 2 | 8 | loc3 |

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql for how to get the row with the max value of a column in each group. Then apply one of those solutions to a subquery that gets the difference between max and min.

Comment: And clarify the PK on your locations table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is with a correlated subquery that will return the `location`:

```
SELECT i.code, i.value,
       (SELECT l.location 
        FROM Locations l 
        WHERE l.code = i.code 
        ORDER BY l.max - l.min DESC LIMIT 1) location
FROM Items i
```

Or if you are using MySql 8.0+ with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT i.code, i.value, l.location
FROM Items i 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY max - min DESC) rn 
  FROM Locations  
) l ON l.code = i.code AND l.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ac8b617862b7c1affceb405e696357c).
Results:

| code | value | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | loc2 |
| 2 | 8 | loc3 |

Comment: I found the first solution that you've proposed few hours ago. I'm using MySQL 5.7 and I cannot use the second version.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can join with the subquery for max diff

```
    select t.code, t.value, c.localtion 
    from locations c 
    inner join  (
        select a.code, a.value, max(max-min) max_val
        from items a
        inner join Locations b on a.code = b.code 

        ) t on t.code = c.code and t.max_val =(c.max-c.min)
```